# Wait for specific packet after connection establishment in local socket

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, localhost

I'm currently working on a C++ application that communicates with my browser using WebSockets. The connection is only local, there won't ever be any non-local socket.

Currently my C++ code looks like that (just for an example):

```
while (true) {
    WebSocket *socket = server->accept () ;
    socket->read (buffer, 256) ;
}
```

And my javascript code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket ("ws://localhost:4564") ;
socket.onopen = function () {
    socket.send("Hello my name is Holt!");
} ;
```

As you can see, I'm waiting for a packet that should be sent as soon as the connection is openned. So I got 2 questions:

- First, are there any way to send this information directly inside the connection? (I think no, so it's why my second question comes for...)?
- Second, knowing that the connection is local, is that possible that the server accept the socket without being able to retrieve the packet after?

To add a bit more information, the current C++ application is based on Qt 5.3 with the QtWebSockets module and the javascript code is  a Google Chrome extension that will run a script on specific websites.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

1. After you establish websocket connection between client and server, in client, when connection is alive, you can call `socket.send()` when you want to send data to server.
2. Even connection local, server is still need wait and receive data, which is a full TCP/IP data transfer process.

Comment: For 2., I know how WebSockets work, my question is "Are there any problem that may occurs between the connection and the first 'send' that would cause my C++ application to block forever?"

Comment: I think it is ok, after server `accept`. it can `read` the data client send.